# Should a REST API be protective of data behind?

Tags: rest, api

On DELETE queries that will possibly cascade into removing a lot of data, should my REST API blindly proceed or warn about it and ask for confirmation ?

I'm building an API that abstracts the manipulation of complex data stored in a relational DB. Removing an item that is referenced by other items should logically remove them to, and then cascade.

A simple example (unrelated to the real case) would be a set of three "Tree/Branch/Leaf" tables: Leaf rows have a foreign key to a Branch's id, and Branch rows similarly include a Tree id. The API enables DELETE at any level, but if you remove a Tree item, it will internally cascade into removing all the Branchs and Leafs that directly or indirectly reference it.

So on a DELETE query for a Tree, the API could:

- just comply and do all cascading removals
- refuse on grounds that it would break integrity, so you have to remove all dependent items manually first (not really practical)
- don't remove anything and send back a statement "this would remove 1 tree, 31 branchs and 987 leafs, please confirm". Confirmation could take the form of an additional header or a suffix in URL (/force), but neither are very REST and in my experience such things are often directly bypassed when writing clients (only the delete+confirm query is actually sent). I also hesitate on the HTTP code for such a reply.

I tend to think that the API should stay simple and that foolsafe protection should be in the client, but would appreciate external wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual for questions like these, the answer really is 'it depends'. Personally, if you would go for the route of having to 'confirm' a large deletion, I would instead:

1. Add a `depth` or `cascading` header. Instead of 'do you really want this?' you know ask your developers to make sure they want to do a deep delete. `Depth` is a standard header but appears in the WebDAV spec. `Cascading` wouldn't be, so you might prefix it with `X-` depending on whether you feel that that's a good idea =)
2. Respond with a `409` if that header was not specified. This is how WebDAV does it and makes a lot of sense here.

However, from my point of view I think I would rather have an 'undelete' option.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I think I'll try the 'undelete' idea without changing everything too much, thus making deletion straightforward and restoring possible. Still no idea on how to fit that undelete in the REST model, though.

Comment: @Tehel one possibility is to make the item available in a separate 'trash' collection.